# Fixed effects in statsmodels.api.ols

Tags: python, statsmodels

Is there a way to add fixed effects in `statsmodels.api.ols` or `statsmodels.formula.api.ols` without creating dummy variables manually?

Comment: fixed effects are categorical variables and are generated by patsy when using the formula interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`statsmodels` does not support fixed effect regression.  However, the package [`linearmodels`](https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/devel/) does.

```py
from linearmodels.panel import PanelOLS
import pandas as pd
from linearmodels.datasets import wage_panel
import statsmodels.api as sm

data = wage_panel.load()
year = pd.Categorical(data.year)
data = data.set_index(["nr", "year"])
data["year"] = year

exog_vars = ["expersq", "union", "married", "year"]
exog = sm.add_constant(data[exog_vars])
mod = PanelOLS(data.lwage, exog, entity_effects=True)
fe_res = mod.fit()
print(fe_res)
```

This prints

```
                          PanelOLS Estimation Summary
================================================================================
Dep. Variable:                  lwage   R-squared:                        0.1806
Estimator:                   PanelOLS   R-squared (Between):             -0.0052
No. Observations:                4360   R-squared (Within):               0.1806
Date:                Wed, Feb 16 2022   R-squared (Overall):              0.0807
Time:                        12:49:00   Log-likelihood                   -1324.8
Cov. Estimator:            Unadjusted
                                        F-statistic:                      83.851
Entities:                         545   P-value                           0.0000
Avg Obs:                       8.0000   Distribution:                 F(10,3805)
Min Obs:                       8.0000
Max Obs:                       8.0000   F-statistic (robust):             83.851
                                        P-value                           0.0000
Time periods:                       8   Distribution:                 F(10,3805)
Avg Obs:                       545.00
Min Obs:                       545.00
Max Obs:                       545.00

                             Parameter Estimates
==============================================================================
            Parameter  Std. Err.     T-stat    P-value    Lower CI    Upper CI
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const          1.4260     0.0183     77.748     0.0000      1.3901      1.4620
expersq       -0.0052     0.0007    -7.3612     0.0000     -0.0066     -0.0038
union          0.0800     0.0193     4.1430     0.0000      0.0421      0.1179
married        0.0467     0.0183     2.5494     0.0108      0.0108      0.0826
year.1981      0.1512     0.0219     6.8883     0.0000      0.1082      0.1942
year.1982      0.2530     0.0244     10.360     0.0000      0.2051      0.3008
year.1983      0.3544     0.0292     12.121     0.0000      0.2971      0.4118
year.1984      0.4901     0.0362     13.529     0.0000      0.4191      0.5611
year.1985      0.6175     0.0452     13.648     0.0000      0.5288      0.7062
year.1986      0.7655     0.0561     13.638     0.0000      0.6555      0.8755
year.1987      0.9250     0.0688     13.450     0.0000      0.7902      1.0599
==============================================================================

F-test for Poolability: 9.1568
P-value: 0.0000
Distribution: F(544,3805)

Included effects: Entity
```

The line `Included effects: Entity` indicates that entity, aka fixed, effects have been included.